# Facing url issues in the joomla?

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I am using joomla and having issues in the url.

Its coming like this:

http://localhost/joomla/restaurant-reviews/view/6?task=view

and it should be like this

```
http://localhost/joomla/restaurant-reviews/view/6
```

$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=' . $option . '&id=' .$row->id . '&task=view');

Code above generating url.

and router.php have these two functions.

```
 function ReviewsBuildRoute(&$query)
 {
   $segments = array();
    if (isset($query['task']))
    {
      $segments[] = $query['task'];
    }
   if(isset($query['id']))
    {
      $segments[] = $query['id'];
      unset($query['id']);
    }
    return $segments;
 }
 function ReviewsParseRoute($segments)
 {
   $vars = array();
   $vars['task'] = $segments[0];
   $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
   return $vars;
 }
```